# IIS requests occationally get sutck in BeginRequest - IIS Web Code

Tags: iis

We have a web application that runs on 6 web servers with HAProxy as the load balancer. We use web deploy to sync our IIS and application across all web servers. Starting January some of customers starting reporting application slow downs. After a lot of work we found that request coming to IIS at random times get stuck in BeingRequest state of IIS Web Core. I am attaching a screenshot from one of my server. Any insight into the issue will be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Fahad

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue but my requests are stuck in a different part of IIS. If anyone has any input there you may also find it useful - [Debugging requests which are 'stuck' in an IIS worker process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137466/debugging-requests-which-are-stuck-in-an-iis-worker-process)

In the screenshot you give your oldest request is 16s old - do they stay in forever or are they just very slow to process? If they don't process is the oldest request in the queue always exactly the same URL and if so can you trigger the issue with that URL?

If they do eventually process (or even if they don't) a good first step for you would be to run Failed Request Tracing/Logging - you can configure it directly in inetmgr at site level. Looking at the compact output will give you an overview of if your requests are being sent on loops around IIS or if there is anything triggering that you wouldn't expect in the life of the request.

If they do eventually process also look into utilisation exhaustion - maybe IIS is just crawling as it's struggling for CPU/RAM/IO - check out the usual suspects.